# Cohomological dimension of finitely presented group

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

I have a group of cohomological dimension 2 generated by two elements. Is it possible to deduce that the group is commutative or, more generally, does $\mathrm{cd}\ G=2$ imply anything about the relations that $G$ must satisfy?

Comment: A concrete example: Take figure 8 knot (or any nontrivial 2-bridge knot). Then the fundamental group of the complement is 2-generated and has cohomological dimension 2. 

Comment: Or any Baumslag--Solitar group (presentation $\langle a,b\mid ba^mb^{-1}=b^n\rangle$ ).

Comment: Oh, I see that Lee Mosher wrote something similar in a comment below.  The bottom line is that there is a huge bestiary of groups of cohomological dimension two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quotient of the free group of rank 2 by a random, long relator has cohomological dimension 2 and is not commutative.

Comment: In fact, quotient *any* relator that isn't a proper power, or primitive, works as well.

Comment: Do you know an old reference? Gromov's random group theorem is overkill, one could just use that a random relator will be small-cancellation, but was this observation made before Gromov? Anyway, an answer is more useful if it provides at least some reference. 

Comment: Lyndon, "Cohomology Theory of Groups with a Single Defining Relation".


Comment: Ok, I guess it follows from the Magnus-Moldovanskii hierarchy. Wise's recent results also imply the virtual cohomological dimension is $\leq 2$ in the presence of torsion. 

Comment: I wasn't thinking so much about Gromov's random groups as "any old random thing you want to do", the point being that cd G = 2 implies just about nothing about relators, and that it's quite easy to construct oodles of examples with cd G = 2 and no particular pattern to the relators. But I quite forgot about one relator groups! Which really nails in the point.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Cohomological dimension 2 really doesn't mean much, then... Pity. How about if the group is almost Abelian, e.g. $[[a,b],a]=[[a,b],b]=e$ (for $a,b$ the two generators). My intuition told me that in this case $\mathrm{cd}\ G=2$ implies that $G$ must in fact be Abelian, but then my intuition tells me all sorts of funny things...

Comment: Well, in this case $G$ is a central cyclic extension of a 2-generator abelian group, so this problem should be fairly straightforward (though I haven't got time to work out the answer).  The comments aren't very noticeable - if you asked this as a separate question, I bet you'd get an answer very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

To complement @Lee's answer, in "Classification of soluble groups of cohomological dimension two", (Math Z, 1979), Dion Gildenhuys does exactly what he claims, so you can see what you get under very strong additional conditions.

Comment: Here's a concrete example of this type, one of my favorite groups: the solvable Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(1,n) = <a,t | tat^{-1}=a^n>$.